# Cover letter for journal submission

Tags: publications, paper-submission

I'm submitting to a journal. There is a drop down menu to choose your area, and each area has a specified editor with his name readily found on the journal instructions. So the assigned editor is known. Should I refer the cover letter to the editor in chief or the editor.

Answer (score 1):

If unsure, just write "Dear Editor".

On the other hand, addressing the editor personally adds a nice personal touch.  So there is nothing wrong with either addressing the specific editor: If the manuscript got reassigned to a different editor, they will be aware of that and realized that you addressed it personally to the specific editor.